# Mathematica ListLogPlot with input data from other list

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Lets say I have function $f[x,y]$, I would like to plot this function for particular combinations (x,y) which I have at another list:

```
Points = {{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}, ...};
```

Intuitively speaking it should look like this

```
ListLogPlot[f[x,y] /. {x,y}->Points]
```

But of course it is not correct syntax and I am not sure how to make this work. Do anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Dear Halirutan, [your solution works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149821/mathematica-listlogplot-with-input-data-from-other-list#comment401691_149821), but how can I choose which variable (x or y) would be on the x-axis of the plot?

Comment: Something along `ListLogPlot[f@@@Points]` should work.

Comment: `ListLogPlot[Transpose[f@@@Points]]` if you want to switch x and y axis

Comment: @winten: In general, you will receive far better answers when you include a *small* (!) example that actually shows what you are trying. Include a sample function and points. It was not clear that `f` is a function f: R^2 -> R^2 which is why you had to make a clarification.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an idea because it lacks information:

```
Points = {{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 12}};
MapThread[f, Points];
f[x_, y_] := {x, y*200}
ListLogPlot[f @@@ Points]
```

Answer (score 2):

In other situations you might have a look at `Map` (`/@`)

Vector of value pairs

```
m1 = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {10, 2}];
```

Matrix of value pairs

```
m2 = Partition[m1, 5];
```

Some function

```
f[{x_, y_}] := x*y
```

Plot vector

```
ListLogPlot[f /@ m1, Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

Plot matrix

```
ListLogPlot[Map[f, m2, {2}], Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]